# Executing an command in Azure Bash from C#

Tags: c#, bash, azure, .net-core

I have an Azure enviroment which I need to manage through a C# program. To properly manage the environment, I need to execute some .sh files.
I want to make a routine so the command is executed after a certain amount of time and also with some parameters. Currently I am executing a .sh file manually from a command line.

Im looking for a way to call the .sh file through C#. However I could not find any documentation about this. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, you need to tell where you want to run the bash file in the Azure environment?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "exec" command to execute linux commands in C#. Instead you can use "`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`" and "`System.Diagnostics.Process`". Since You need to run shell commands it isn't possible to use cmd ,Hence you can use cygwin as application to execute them.

Hence this code worked,

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe",command);
```

and then

```
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

proc.Start();
```

Complete code would be like:

```
private void runCom(string command)
{
    ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c" + command);
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Hope it helps.